# Is the law of a Dirichlet process a continuous function of its base measure?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(S,d)$ be a complete and separable metric space. Let $\alpha_n > 0$ with $\alpha_n\to\alpha_\infty$. Let $H_n$ be Borel probability measures on $S$ with $H_n\to H_\infty$ weakly. (That is, $\int_S f\,dH_n\to\int_S f\,dH_\infty$ for all bounded, continuous $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$.)

Let $X_n$ be a [Dirichlet process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process) with base distribution $H_n$ and concentration parameter $\alpha_n$. Then $X_n$ is a random variable taking values in $M_1(S)$, the set of Borel probability measures on $S$. If we equip $M_1(S)$ with the [Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) (which metrizes weak convergence), then it is also a complete and separable metric space.

The question: Does $X_n$ converge in distribution to $X_\infty$? Or, put another way, if $\textrm{DP}(H_n,\alpha_n)$ denotes the law of $X_n$, then does $\textrm{DP}(H_n,\alpha_n)\to\textrm{DP}(H_\infty,\alpha_\infty)$ weakly as $n\to\infty$?

I'm pretty sure I can prove this myself, but I was hoping to see if anyone knew a reference for it. It seems like a basic property of Dirichlet processes, so it must be somewhere in the literature. A reference would not only prevent me from reinventing the wheel, but would also possibly lead me to other useful properties I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly recent paper by G. Last containing a characterization of the Dirichlet process that should be made to order for your question:
https://doi.org/10.1007/s10959-019-00923-y

Comment: Thank you. I cannot immediately see how this gives what I'm looking for, but I will look more closely at it later. It does seem like a heavy tool, though, to establish a continuity property that I was assuming is fairly fundamental in the subject.

Comment: If the convergence of $(\alpha_n)$ and $(H_n)$ suffices to show that $(X_n)$ is tight, then Last's result seems like it would guarantee uniqueness of subsequential limits.